# Angular form valid state does not update when changing fields thru Javascript (IE 11)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm currently developing a feature that will update fields based on a logic previously set up, in the sense that a change on field A will cascade itself to field B:

Based on the changed field I apply the value to another field:

```
if(fieldsChanged != undefined){
  for(var x = 0; x < fieldsChanged.length; x++ ){
       if(menuItem[fieldsChanged[x]+'Old'] == undefined){
          menuItem[fieldsChanged[x]+'Old'] = menuItem[fieldsChanged[x]];
         }
       menuItem[fieldsChanged[x]+'New'] = menuItem[priceType+'New'];
       menuItem[fieldsChanged[x]] = menuItem[priceType+'New'];
       var del = document.getElementById(fieldsChanged[x] + menuItem.inputId);                    
       alert(del.validity);
       var $del = angular.element(del); 
       del.value = document.getElementById(priceType + menuItem.inputId).value;
       del.validity = document.getElementById(priceType + menuItem.inputId).validity;
       del.setAttribute('value',document.getElementById(priceType + menuItem.inputId).value);
       $del.triggerHandler('input');
       del.focus();
       document.getElementById(priceType + menuItem.inputId).focus();
       del.focus();
       document.getElementById(priceType + menuItem.inputId).focus();     
     }
```

}

However. in Internet explorer only, the valid state of the input will not change, when invalid values were previously set:

input -7 to input A
input 8 to input B, which replicates itself to input A(becomes 8 too)

Form will show itself as $IsValid = False and input A class will show the invalid styling:

HTML:

```
Input A(input tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid md-input ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-required ng-touched" id="eatIn_7146_108" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="mbEatIn" ng-change="mbpVm.priceChange(mbEatIn, mi, 'eatIn', this)" ng-init="mbEatIn= mi.eatInCalc;" ng-required="false" ng-max="99.99" ng-min="0.01")

Input B(input tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid md-input ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-required ng-touched" id="takeOut_7146_108" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="mbTakeOut" ng-change="mbpVm.priceChange(mbTakeOut, mi, 'takeOut', this )" ng-init="mbTakeOut= mi.takeOutCalc;" ng-required="false" ng-max="99.99" ng-min="0.01")
```

How should I be doing this ? What is wrong and why isn't Angular rechecking the form validity ?

PS: AngularJS 1.3 version, and it does work on Chrome.